# RTC chip mcp7941x not working with dtoverlay i2c-rtc-gpio

Tags: rtc, mcp79410

I have an mcp79310 RTC chip installed on gpio pins 22 & 23, and I am attempting to use it with `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc-gpio,mcp7941x,i2c_gpio_sda=22,i2c_gpio_scl=23` in `/boot/config.txt` and adding `rtc-mcp7941x` to `/etc/modules`.

After rebooting, upon checking with `$ timedatectl` I get this result:

`Failed to query server: Failed to read RTC: Invalid argument`

Running `$ i2cdetect -y 11` shows:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

So nothing seems to be wrong so far. Checking `$ dmesg|grep rtc` shows:

```
[    4.299290] i2c-gpio i2c-gpio-rtc@0: using lines 22 (SDA) and 23 (SCL)
[    5.733573] rtc-ds1307 11-006f: registered as rtc0
```

With this failure to read the RTC, I removed the dtoverlay for it and added the `i2c-gpio` dtoverlay in /boot/config.txt:

`dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=22,i2c_gpio_scl=23`

After rebooting, I tested the RTC chip directly using i2cget & i2cset (per this article - https://tom.meinlschmidt.org/2014/02/19/mcp7940-rtc-with-pi/), and it works perfectly.

After further experimentation, if I start up the Raspi with the `dtoverlay=i2c-gpio` enabled, but `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc-gpio` disabled, then disable the first dtoverlay and re-enable the second, and then reboot, the RTC works perfectly when queried by `timedatectl`.

In other words, if I booting, starting the RTC chip without tying it to the rtc dtoverlay, then reboot with the rtc dtoverlay it works. If I remove the RTC battery and power down, then on power-up I have to go through the same two-step boot process to get it working again.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

**UPDATE:** The problem seems to resolve after about 30 secs from the finish of boot up. I believe it may happen when timedatectl syncs its system clock (I am using chrony for NTP). If I try setting it up manually after startup:

`# echo mcp7941x 0x6f > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-11/new_device`

It starts working right away after I call `hwclock -r`. If I put the same code into `/etc/rc.local` it still takes about 30 secs before the RTC works.

Here's a schematic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add pull-ups to 3V3 to GPIO 22 and 23.  The I2C bus requires pull-ups on SDA and SCL.

For reference the Pi has 1k8 resistors fitted between 3V3 and GPIO 2 and 3V3 and GPIO 3.

Comment: I do have pullups - 10k. I added a schematic to show.